# How to get rid of the "{" and "}" in json?

Tags: php, json, pannellum

I'm working on the map hotspots. Which are needs to correct exactly to the manual. But from my code. There're more character interfere the plugin interpret.

This is my json:

```
[{//this is the extra
  "hs1": {
    "title": "Door Way",
    "hfov": "110",
    "pitch": "-3",
    "yaw": "130",
    "type": "equirectangular",
    "panorama": "\/photos\/Door-Way-5a57aff9c30b7.jpg",
    "hotSpots": [{
      "id": "17",
      "pitch": "-0.8069389",
      "yaw": "-174.40953",
      "type": "info",
      "text": "Closet"
    }]
  }
},//extra
{//extra
  "hs2": {
    "title": "Toilet",
    "hfov": "110",
    "pitch": "-3",
    "yaw": "130",
    "type": "equirectangular",
    "panorama": "\/photos\/Toilet-5a58b8ed2cb23.jpg",
    "hotSpots": ""
  }
}//extra]
```

In every set of new glossary, there is an extra "{}" coming in.

This is my PHP:

```
$result[]=array(
    "hs".$rec_scnArr['id']=>
    array(
    "title"=>$rec_scnArr['title'],
    "hfov"=>$rec_scnArr['hfov'],
    "pitch"=>$rec_scnArr['pitch'],
    "yaw"=>$rec_scnArr['yaw'],
    "type"=>"equirectangular",
    "panorama"=>"/photos/".$rec_sIMG['pic_file'],
    "hotSpots"=>$hotSpots           //$hotSpots is the array
    )
);

echo json_encode($result,true);
```

I'm sure there must be something wrong with the php loop. But I cannot see. [This is the example](https://pannellum.org/documentation/examples/tour/) from the plugin page.

So the question is how to get rid of the extra "[" and "{" in the json code? I think it's doesn't matter but it is. When I put the raw code in there. It's working. Then I think this is the problem.

Comment: Maybe you should post how exactly you want the data to look like, I have a feeling it's not going to be valid JSON.

Comment: Are you looking to simplify the items in your array, from single property objects ("hs1"'s value in the first, "hs2"'s value in the second)?

Comment: *"How to get rid of the “{” and “}” in json?*" -- you don't want to get rid of those curly braces because the JSON probably becomes invalid this way. You want to decode the JSON into an array, change the structure of the array and probably encode it again as JSON (or not).

Comment: Nice try guys, I got one wise guy already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you want is a *single object* with multiple properties instead of an array of objects each having a single property.

To achieve this you need to add all the properties to the same array:

```
$result["hs".$rec_scnArr['id']] = array(
    "title"=>$rec_scnArr['title'],
    "hfov"=>$rec_scnArr['hfov'],
    "pitch"=>$rec_scnArr['pitch'],
    "yaw"=>$rec_scnArr['yaw'],
    "type"=>"equirectangular",
    "panorama"=>"/photos/".$rec_sIMG['pic_file'],
    "hotSpots"=>$hotSpots           //$hotSpots is the array
);

echo json_encode($result,true);
```

Comment: After hours of trying. Finally found a solution. Thank you very much. It's easy but never get it out.